# Как сделать чтобы FAB скрылся когда RecyclerView на самом нижнем положении?

Tags: java, android

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы FAB скрылся когда RecyclerView на самом нижнем положении (как в приложении Telegram на экране переписки). Как это сделать?

```
fab = this.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        messagesList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            if (dy > 0) {
                fab.show();
                Log.i(TAG, "вниз");
            } else {
                fab.hide();
                Log.i(TAG, "вверх");
            }


        }
    });
    fab.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `canScrollVertically()`:

```
messagesList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
           //1- тест вертикального скролла вниз
           //-1 - тест вертикального скролла вверх
           if (!messagesList.canScrollVertically(1) 
              //достигли дна
           else
              //еще нет
        }
}
```

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Когда будет формулировать новый вопрос, озаботьтесь значением термина *чуть выше*